# Help with Dual Spaces - Prove that either $w\in Im(f)$ **or** there exists ${l\in W^{*}}$ such that $f^{*}\left(l\right)=0$ **and** $l(w)=1$"

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I'm in need of some assistance regarding this question. I'm learning Linear Algebra by myself using a university textbook and it has this question regarding Dual Spaces:

"Let there be a linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ between $V,W$ (who are vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$)

Let there be $w\in W$.

Prove that either $w\in Im(f)$ **or** there exists ${l\in W^{*}}$ such that  $f^{*}\left(l\right)=0$ **and** $l(w)=1$"

OK so I know that $f^{*}$ is defined as $W^{*}\rightarrow V^{*}$. I also know(and correct me if I'm wrong) that $l(w)=1$ will occur if $w$ is a vector in the Base for $W$

I understand the first option they want me to prove: if I take some vector in $W$ then it is an image of some vector from $V$ but I don't entirely understand the other option...specifically regarding $f^{*}(l)=0$

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Vectors in $W^\ast$ are just linear maps $W \to \mathbb F$ and $f^\ast$ takes a map $W \to \mathbb F$ to the composition $V \to W \to \mathbb F$.  So the second condition states that there exists a linear map $l\colon W \to \mathbb F$ such that the composition $l\circ f$ is zero but $l(w) = 1$.

One way to do this question is to make a clever choice of basis, can you take a basis $\{x_i\}_i$ of $im(f)$ and show that by adding the vector $w$ you still get a linearly independent set $\{x_i, w\}_i$ and therefore this can be extended to a basis $\{x_i, w, y_j\}_{i, j}$ of $W$.  Then take the dual basis $\{x_i^\ast, w^\ast, y_j^\ast\}_{i, j}$ and pick $l$ from that set.